# Installing Homebrew on OS X Mavericks gives SSL Error 9806

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ssl, homebrew

Earlier today, I tried installing Ruby on Rails on my Mac running OS X Mavericks. I found [this handy tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks) on how to install it on Mavericks so I started with installing Homebrew. I copy pasted the install line on my terminal. It prompted me to install XCode CLI so I let it, after which, I got back to my terminal to install Homebrew, however, it gave me this error:

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': SSLRead() return error -9806
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

Thinking that the installation failed, I tried it again, but it told me that Homebrew was installed properly:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
```

It then gave me the uninstall command. Upon trying that, it told me that

```
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

Now I'm lost. I'm pretty sure I can't shrug this step off because clearly, I didn't manage to install Homebrew properly and I can't seem to uninstall it either.

How should I proceed from here? I am not that well versed with OS X Terminal commands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was a curious case but this is how I managed to get it to work. 
Thanks to katezaps for the lead.

When installing homebrew, you need XCodes CLI. Homebrews site gives you a terminal command where it will prompt you to install XCodes CLI if you don't have it yet. After you dl and install CLI, you can go back to the terminal and continue installing homebrew by hitting return.

However, the curious part was that in my case, it seemed that CLI didn't install properly through homebrews command -- and therefore, homebrew hit that SSL error. I had to download XCode and do the xcode install command again for the CLI. That just safeguards that you installed CLI properly.

Now, if you try and run homebrews install command again, it will tell you that you have homebrew already, and that you need to uninstall. However, if you run that uninstall command, nothing happens since it can't find homebrew.

To wipe homebrew again, I used this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/.git
<Password Prompt here>
chown <your_username> /usr/local
```

and tried the install again.

Now it installed without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error before, too. You need to update your XCode and finish installing it directly through opening the app before you can download homebrew

Comment: Okay, I have problems with that. 1) How can homebrew be installed by then when it won't install now and I can't uninstall it because it's not there (apparently). Would XCode magically uninstall/wipe homebrew so that I won't have problems when I install it again? 2) XCode works on the latest OS X Version and it would take time for me to update.

Comment: Homebrew requires the command line tools from XCode to work properly. You need to accept the terms and agreements and install it before brew will work. You may not need to have the latest version of XCode for it to work properly, but I'm not sure on that. I just know it needs the command line tools from XCode, and that's not fully installed until you open up XCode and finish the installation from there.

Comment: Oh so what you mean to tell me is that when I was prompted to install the XCode CLI tools when I ran the command to install homebrew from the terminal, that didn't fully install the CLI Tools?

Comment: Exactly - so it's getting all funky because it sort of has it but doesn't really.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I'll try this right now and hopefully it works.